# jQuery UI autocomplete doesn't work on deployed application but works on localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, heroku, autocomplete

I have one problem that I can't understand. I've built many web applications under jQuery UI and with jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin

```
$("#autocompleteObchod").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        console.log('ok');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/eshops/default/search",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                q: request.term
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.name,
                        value: item.name,
                        id: item.uuid
                    };
                }));
            }
        } );
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#form-eshopId').val(ui.item.id);
    }
} );
```

This code works on my localhost.

But when I deploy my application via Dokku (heroku), autocomplete wont work. Nothing. No event triggered, no error in console, no error with javascript. Nothing. Do you guys had similar problem ? I'm out of energy with this.

If you want to check my application check http://dev.dobravec.info/organizations/
And try search something at first inline search component.

[image: Search component]

Comment: did you try to debug your code on server with developer tools? Is AJAX call returns success? Your url might be the problem.

Comment: @lunaks - this is problem, no no ajax is triggered, nothing is triggered when I'm typing... But locally works without any problem.

Comment: I try to debug but i couldn't find your scripts. There is no ajax call on the server.( Edit: my bad i found it)

Comment: @lunaks there it is http://dev.dobravec.info/assets/scripts/dobravec.min.js and try to search via (`ctrl + f or cmd + f`) **#autocompleteObchod** I'm using gulp to minify my javascript. (Same code works on my local machine) PS: Did you get `console.log('Ok')` in your console ?

Comment: In your html there is an attr called autocomplete="off" making it "on" solves the problem. Is it the same in your local?

Comment: @lunaks my local code is with attribute autocomplete="off" Buy I'm doing this in my html `<input id="autocompleteObchod" n:name="eshop" class="inputFields custom_autocomplete browser-default" placeholder="Obchod" >` . Maybe `.autocomplete()` function set this attribute to `off` by default.

Comment: Is there any way you hard coded your javascript to use `localhost`?

Comment: @Mike right, I'm using framework method to generate link for ajax

Comment: @lunaks `autocomplete="on"` doesn't solve problem. Did you try it in your debug tool and it worked for you ? I've deployed new version of application with attribute setted to `on` and it doesnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have something wrong with you jquery ui version.
First of all I tried to debug the code of your autocomplete code version. It never fires out because it never receives arguments from you. For script your call is like calling `autocomplete({})` - does nothing.

What the hell I thought - somebody broke autocomplete?

I went to jquery ui cdn, copied autocomplete function and pasted it to console. And initialized autocomplete on your input again. And it works fine.

[image]

So I dont know why, I dont know who - but somebody has edited your version of autocomplete. Get the new one and enjoy.

Try for yourself:

First ctrl+v jquery ui autocomplete function to console:

```js
/*!
 * jQuery UI Autocomplete 1.12.0
 * http://jqueryui.com
 *
 * Copyright jQuery Foundation and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license.
 * http://jquery.org/license
 */

//>>label: Autocomplete
//>>group: Widgets
//>>description: Lists suggested words as the user is typing.
//>>docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
//>>demos: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
//>>css.structure: ../../themes/base/core.css
//>>css.structure: ../../themes/base/autocomplete.css
//>>css.theme: ../../themes/base/theme.css



$.widget( "ui.autocomplete", {
 version: "1.12.0",
 defaultElement: "<input>",
 options: {
  appendTo: null,
  autoFocus: false,
  delay: 300,
  minLength: 1,
  position: {
   my: "left top",
   at: "left bottom",
   collision: "none"
  },
  source: null,

  // Callbacks
  change: null,
  close: null,
  focus: null,
  open: null,
  response: null,
  search: null,
  select: null
 },

 requestIndex: 0,
 pending: 0,

 _create: function() {

  // Some browsers only repeat keydown events, not keypress events,
  // so we use the suppressKeyPress flag to determine if we've already
  // handled the keydown event. #7269
  // Unfortunately the code for & in keypress is the same as the up arrow,
  // so we use the suppressKeyPressRepeat flag to avoid handling keypress
  // events when we know the keydown event was used to modify the
  // search term. #7799
  var suppressKeyPress, suppressKeyPressRepeat, suppressInput,
   nodeName = this.element[ 0 ].nodeName.toLowerCase(),
   isTextarea = nodeName === "textarea",
   isInput = nodeName === "input";

  // Textareas are always multi-line
  // Inputs are always single-line, even if inside a contentEditable element
  // IE also treats inputs as contentEditable
  // All other element types are determined by whether or not they're contentEditable
  this.isMultiLine = isTextarea || !isInput && this._isContentEditable( this.element );

  this.valueMethod = this.element[ isTextarea || isInput ? "val" : "text" ];
  this.isNewMenu = true;

  this._addClass( "ui-autocomplete-input" );
  this.element.attr( "autocomplete", "off" );

  this._on( this.element, {
   keydown: function( event ) {
    if ( this.element.prop( "readOnly" ) ) {
     suppressKeyPress = true;
     suppressInput = true;
     suppressKeyPressRepeat = true;
     return;
    }

    suppressKeyPress = false;
    suppressInput = false;
    suppressKeyPressRepeat = false;
    var keyCode = $.ui.keyCode;
    switch ( event.keyCode ) {
    case keyCode.PAGE_UP:
     suppressKeyPress = true;
     this._move( "previousPage", event );
     break;
    case keyCode.PAGE_DOWN:
     suppressKeyPress = true;
     this._move( "nextPage", event );
     break;
    case keyCode.UP:
     suppressKeyPress = true;
     this._keyEvent( "previous", event );
     break;
    case keyCode.DOWN:
     suppressKeyPress = true;
     this._keyEvent( "next", event );
     break;
    case keyCode.ENTER:

     // when menu is open and has focus
     if ( this.menu.active ) {

      // #6055 - Opera still allows the keypress to occur
      // which causes forms to submit
      suppressKeyPress = true;
      event.preventDefault();
      this.menu.select( event );
     }
     break;
    case keyCode.TAB:
     if ( this.menu.active ) {
      this.menu.select( event );
     }
     break;
    case keyCode.ESCAPE:
     if ( this.menu.element.is( ":visible" ) ) {
      if ( !this.isMultiLine ) {
       this._value( this.term );
      }
      this.close( event );

      // Different browsers have different default behavior for escape
      // Single press can mean undo or clear
      // Double press in IE means clear the whole form
      event.preventDefault();
     }
     break;
    default:
     suppressKeyPressRepeat = true;

     // search timeout should be triggered before the input value is changed
     this._searchTimeout( event );
     break;
    }
   },
   keypress: function( event ) {
    if ( suppressKeyPress ) {
     suppressKeyPress = false;
     if ( !this.isMultiLine || this.menu.element.is( ":visible" ) ) {
      event.preventDefault();
     }
     return;
    }
    if ( suppressKeyPressRepeat ) {
     return;
    }

    // Replicate some key handlers to allow them to repeat in Firefox and Opera
    var keyCode = $.ui.keyCode;
    switch ( event.keyCode ) {
    case keyCode.PAGE_UP:
     this._move( "previousPage", event );
     break;
    case keyCode.PAGE_DOWN:
     this._move( "nextPage", event );
     break;
    case keyCode.UP:
     this._keyEvent( "previous", event );
     break;
    case keyCode.DOWN:
     this._keyEvent( "next", event );
     break;
    }
   },
   input: function( event ) {
    if ( suppressInput ) {
     suppressInput = false;
     event.preventDefault();
     return;
    }
    this._searchTimeout( event );
   },
   focus: function() {
    this.selectedItem = null;
    this.previous = this._value();
   },
   blur: function( event ) {
    if ( this.cancelBlur ) {
     delete this.cancelBlur;
     return;
    }

    clearTimeout( this.searching );
    this.close( event );
    this._change( event );
   }
  } );

  this._initSource();
  this.menu = $( "<ul>" )
   .appendTo( this._appendTo() )
   .menu( {

    // disable ARIA support, the live region takes care of that
    role: null
   } )
   .hide()
   .menu( "instance" );

  this._addClass( this.menu.element, "ui-autocomplete", "ui-front" );
  this._on( this.menu.element, {
   mousedown: function( event ) {

    // prevent moving focus out of the text field
    event.preventDefault();

    // IE doesn't prevent moving focus even with event.preventDefault()
    // so we set a flag to know when we should ignore the blur event
    this.cancelBlur = true;
    this._delay( function() {
     delete this.cancelBlur;

     // Support: IE 8 only
     // Right clicking a menu item or selecting text from the menu items will
     // result in focus moving out of the input. However, we've already received
     // and ignored the blur event because of the cancelBlur flag set above. So
     // we restore focus to ensure that the menu closes properly based on the user's
     // next actions.
     if ( this.element[ 0 ] !== $.ui.safeActiveElement( this.document[ 0 ] ) ) {
      this.element.trigger( "focus" );
     }
    } );
   },
   menufocus: function( event, ui ) {
    var label, item;

    // support: Firefox
    // Prevent accidental activation of menu items in Firefox (#7024 #9118)
    if ( this.isNewMenu ) {
     this.isNewMenu = false;
     if ( event.originalEvent && /^mouse/.test( event.originalEvent.type ) ) {
      this.menu.blur();

      this.document.one( "mousemove", function() {
       $( event.target ).trigger( event.originalEvent );
      } );

      return;
     }
    }

    item = ui.item.data( "ui-autocomplete-item" );
    if ( false !== this._trigger( "focus", event, { item: item } ) ) {

     // use value to match what will end up in the input, if it was a key event
     if ( event.originalEvent && /^key/.test( event.originalEvent.type ) ) {
      this._value( item.value );
     }
    }

    // Announce the value in the liveRegion
    label = ui.item.attr( "aria-label" ) || item.value;
    if ( label && $.trim( label ).length ) {
     this.liveRegion.children().hide();
     $( "<div>" ).text( label ).appendTo( this.liveRegion );
    }
   },
   menuselect: function( event, ui ) {
    var item = ui.item.data( "ui-autocomplete-item" ),
     previous = this.previous;

    // Only trigger when focus was lost (click on menu)
    if ( this.element[ 0 ] !== $.ui.safeActiveElement( this.document[ 0 ] ) ) {
     this.element.trigger( "focus" );
     this.previous = previous;

     // #6109 - IE triggers two focus events and the second
     // is asynchronous, so we need to reset the previous
     // term synchronously and asynchronously :-(
     this._delay( function() {
      this.previous = previous;
      this.selectedItem = item;
     } );
    }

    if ( false !== this._trigger( "select", event, { item: item } ) ) {
     this._value( item.value );
    }

    // reset the term after the select event
    // this allows custom select handling to work properly
    this.term = this._value();

    this.close( event );
    this.selectedItem = item;
   }
  } );

  this.liveRegion = $( "<div>", {
   role: "status",
   "aria-live": "assertive",
   "aria-relevant": "additions"
  } )
   .appendTo( this.document[ 0 ].body );

  this._addClass( this.liveRegion, null, "ui-helper-hidden-accessible" );

  // Turning off autocomplete prevents the browser from remembering the
  // value when navigating through history, so we re-enable autocomplete
  // if the page is unloaded before the widget is destroyed. #7790
  this._on( this.window, {
   beforeunload: function() {
    this.element.removeAttr( "autocomplete" );
   }
  } );
 },

 _destroy: function() {
  clearTimeout( this.searching );
  this.element.removeAttr( "autocomplete" );
  this.menu.element.remove();
  this.liveRegion.remove();
 },

 _setOption: function( key, value ) {
  this._super( key, value );
  if ( key === "source" ) {
   this._initSource();
  }
  if ( key === "appendTo" ) {
   this.menu.element.appendTo( this._appendTo() );
  }
  if ( key === "disabled" && value && this.xhr ) {
   this.xhr.abort();
  }
 },

 _isEventTargetInWidget: function( event ) {
  var menuElement = this.menu.element[ 0 ];

  return event.target === this.element[ 0 ] ||
   event.target === menuElement ||
   $.contains( menuElement, event.target );
 },

 _closeOnClickOutside: function( event ) {
  if ( !this._isEventTargetInWidget( event ) ) {
   this.close();
  }
 },

 _appendTo: function() {
  var element = this.options.appendTo;

  if ( element ) {
   element = element.jquery || element.nodeType ?
    $( element ) :
    this.document.find( element ).eq( 0 );
  }

  if ( !element || !element[ 0 ] ) {
   element = this.element.closest( ".ui-front, dialog" );
  }

  if ( !element.length ) {
   element = this.document[ 0 ].body;
  }

  return element;
 },

 _initSource: function() {
  var array, url,
   that = this;
  if ( $.isArray( this.options.source ) ) {
   array = this.options.source;
   this.source = function( request, response ) {
    response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter( array, request.term ) );
   };
  } else if ( typeof this.options.source === "string" ) {
   url = this.options.source;
   this.source = function( request, response ) {
    if ( that.xhr ) {
     that.xhr.abort();
    }
    that.xhr = $.ajax( {
     url: url,
     data: request,
     dataType: "json",
     success: function( data ) {
      response( data );
     },
     error: function() {
      response( [] );
     }
    } );
   };
  } else {
   this.source = this.options.source;
  }
 },

 _searchTimeout: function( event ) {
  clearTimeout( this.searching );
  this.searching = this._delay( function() {

   // Search if the value has changed, or if the user retypes the same value (see #7434)
   var equalValues = this.term === this._value(),
    menuVisible = this.menu.element.is( ":visible" ),
    modifierKey = event.altKey || event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey || event.shiftKey;

   if ( !equalValues || ( equalValues && !menuVisible && !modifierKey ) ) {
    this.selectedItem = null;
    this.search( null, event );
   }
  }, this.options.delay );
 },

 search: function( value, event ) {
  value = value != null ? value : this._value();

  // Always save the actual value, not the one passed as an argument
  this.term = this._value();

  if ( value.length < this.options.minLength ) {
   return this.close( event );
  }

  if ( this._trigger( "search", event ) === false ) {
   return;
  }

  return this._search( value );
 },

 _search: function( value ) {
  this.pending++;
  this._addClass( "ui-autocomplete-loading" );
  this.cancelSearch = false;

  this.source( { term: value }, this._response() );
 },

 _response: function() {
  var index = ++this.requestIndex;

  return $.proxy( function( content ) {
   if ( index === this.requestIndex ) {
    this.__response( content );
   }

   this.pending--;
   if ( !this.pending ) {
    this._removeClass( "ui-autocomplete-loading" );
   }
  }, this );
 },

 __response: function( content ) {
  if ( content ) {
   content = this._normalize( content );
  }
  this._trigger( "response", null, { content: content } );
  if ( !this.options.disabled && content && content.length && !this.cancelSearch ) {
   this._suggest( content );
   this._trigger( "open" );
  } else {

   // use ._close() instead of .close() so we don't cancel future searches
   this._close();
  }
 },

 close: function( event ) {
  this.cancelSearch = true;
  this._close( event );
 },

 _close: function( event ) {

  // Remove the handler that closes the menu on outside clicks
  this._off( this.document, "mousedown" );

  if ( this.menu.element.is( ":visible" ) ) {
   this.menu.element.hide();
   this.menu.blur();
   this.isNewMenu = true;
   this._trigger( "close", event );
  }
 },

 _change: function( event ) {
  if ( this.previous !== this._value() ) {
   this._trigger( "change", event, { item: this.selectedItem } );
  }
 },

 _normalize: function( items ) {

  // assume all items have the right format when the first item is complete
  if ( items.length && items[ 0 ].label && items[ 0 ].value ) {
   return items;
  }
  return $.map( items, function( item ) {
   if ( typeof item === "string" ) {
    return {
     label: item,
     value: item
    };
   }
   return $.extend( {}, item, {
    label: item.label || item.value,
    value: item.value || item.label
   } );
  } );
 },

 _suggest: function( items ) {
  var ul = this.menu.element.empty();
  this._renderMenu( ul, items );
  this.isNewMenu = true;
  this.menu.refresh();

  // Size and position menu
  ul.show();
  this._resizeMenu();
  ul.position( $.extend( {
   of: this.element
  }, this.options.position ) );

  if ( this.options.autoFocus ) {
   this.menu.next();
  }

  // Listen for interactions outside of the widget (#6642)
  this._on( this.document, {
   mousedown: "_closeOnClickOutside"
  } );
 },

 _resizeMenu: function() {
  var ul = this.menu.element;
  ul.outerWidth( Math.max(

   // Firefox wraps long text (possibly a rounding bug)
   // so we add 1px to avoid the wrapping (#7513)
   ul.width( "" ).outerWidth() + 1,
   this.element.outerWidth()
  ) );
 },

 _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
  var that = this;
  $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
   that._renderItemData( ul, item );
  } );
 },

 _renderItemData: function( ul, item ) {
  return this._renderItem( ul, item ).data( "ui-autocomplete-item", item );
 },

 _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
  return $( "<li>" )
   .append( $( "<div>" ).text( item.label ) )
   .appendTo( ul );
 },

 _move: function( direction, event ) {
  if ( !this.menu.element.is( ":visible" ) ) {
   this.search( null, event );
   return;
  }
  if ( this.menu.isFirstItem() && /^previous/.test( direction ) ||
    this.menu.isLastItem() && /^next/.test( direction ) ) {

   if ( !this.isMultiLine ) {
    this._value( this.term );
   }

   this.menu.blur();
   return;
  }
  this.menu[ direction ]( event );
 },

 widget: function() {
  return this.menu.element;
 },

 _value: function() {
  return this.valueMethod.apply( this.element, arguments );
 },

 _keyEvent: function( keyEvent, event ) {
  if ( !this.isMultiLine || this.menu.element.is( ":visible" ) ) {
   this._move( keyEvent, event );

   // Prevents moving cursor to beginning/end of the text field in some browsers
   event.preventDefault();
  }
 },

 // Support: Chrome <=50
 // We should be able to just use this.element.prop( "isContentEditable" )
 // but hidden elements always report false in Chrome.
 // https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=313082
 _isContentEditable: function( element ) {
  if ( !element.length ) {
   return false;
  }

  var editable = element.prop( "contentEditable" );

  if ( editable === "inherit" ) {
    return this._isContentEditable( element.parent() );
  }

  return editable === "true";
 }
} );

$.extend( $.ui.autocomplete, {
 escapeRegex: function( value ) {
  return value.replace( /[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&" );
 },
 filter: function( array, term ) {
  var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( term ), "i" );
  return $.grep( array, function( value ) {
   return matcher.test( value.label || value.value || value );
  } );
 }
} );

// Live region extension, adding a `messages` option
// NOTE: This is an experimental API. We are still investigating
// a full solution for string manipulation and internationalization.
$.widget( "ui.autocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
 options: {
  messages: {
   noResults: "No search results.",
   results: function( amount ) {
    return amount + ( amount > 1 ? " results are" : " result is" ) +
     " available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.";
   }
  }
 },

 __response: function( content ) {
  var message;
  this._superApply( arguments );
  if ( this.options.disabled || this.cancelSearch ) {
   return;
  }
  if ( content && content.length ) {
   message = this.options.messages.results( content.length );
  } else {
   message = this.options.messages.noResults;
  }
  this.liveRegion.children().hide();
  $( "<div>" ).text( message ).appendTo( this.liveRegion );
 }
} );

var widgetsAutocomplete = $.ui.autocomplete;
```

And then, run your script again from console

```
$("#autocompleteObchod").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        console.log('ok');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/eshops/default/search",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                q: request.term
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.name,
                        value: item.name,
                        id: item.uuid
                    };
                }));
            }
        } );
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#form-eshopId').val(ui.item.id);
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I don't know who, because I'm using bower for frontend dependencies... I don't even know that why exactly the same code works on my local machine... I'm using `bower install jquery-ui`

Comment: Anyway, I've put this hardcoded jquery-ui.autocomplete plugin to my code. (So I don't use bower component for autocomplete anymore). Thank you ! You saved my life :)